# Using std::sort to sort Matrix

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Is there a way I can sort matrix elements with the sort function from std?

```
//Using this matrix
vector<vector<string>> mat;
```

For example if you have

```
5 2 1
0 0 2
1 4 3
```

The result would be

```
0 0 1
1 2 2
3 4 5
```

Comment: Sorting matrix makes no sense. You need to clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: I said matrix elements, you should read before writing

Comment: Same thing. Many ways to do that.

Comment: If your matrix is stored contiguously instead of as `vector<vector>`, then yes std::sort would work. But it would sort with respect to storage type. If the matrix is stored in row-major order, the elements would be sorted as you gave in the example. If they are stored in column-major order; they would be sorted column-wise.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use vector<vector>

Comment: Your example sorts each row to be incremental; and THEN sorts the columns by the 2nd row to be incremental.  You can do that with std::sort; no problem.

Comment: I know how to sort the rows incremental, but how do you sort the columns UKMonkey

Comment: @UKMonkey If I understood you right, this would result in `0 0 2 | 1 2 5 | 1 3 4` but this isn't what OP is searching for.

Comment: Why don't you copy the `vector<vector<string>>` to `vector<string>`, std::sort it, and then copy back to `vector<vector<string>>`? If copying is considered to be too expensive, a more sophisticated solution would be to build up a `vector<pair<size_t, size_t>>` (which stores indices of matrix elements) and `std::sort` them with a custom less functor which considers the original matrix to pick up the elements via indices.

Comment: You're right - it's not sorted that way - it's sorted by column and then by row... ohh wow; that's a strange thing to want to do.  So sure - you use std::sort to sort by column; and then you use std::sort to sort each row.  What's the problem?

Comment: Ooh , ok I think I know how to do it UKMonkey thanks!

Comment: Assuming you can't change the type you're using, you probably just need to write yourself a range adapter for the matrix.  Make sure it satisfies `RandomAccessIterator`, and provide a pair of them to `std::sort()`.  Job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the nested vectors without extra data copying by creating a custom wrapper matrix class and define your own iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MyMatrix {
 public:
  using DataStore = std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >;

  // Note: Make sure MyMatrix DO NOT out-live its `data` argument!
  MyMatrix(DataStore& data) : data_(data) {
    // Check that
    //  1. data.size() > 0;
    //  2. data[i].size() > 0 and same for all valid i.
  }

  class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
                                        std::string, int> {
   public:
    Iterator(DataStore& data) : data_(&data), index_(0) {}
    Iterator(DataStore& data, int index) : data_(&data), index_(index) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator& it) : data_(it.data_), index_(it.index_) {}

    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& it) {
      data_ = it.data_;
      index_ = it.index_;
    }
    operator bool() const {
      return index_ >= 0 && index_ < data_->size() * (*data_)[0].size();
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator& it) const {
      return data_ == it.data_ && index_ == it.index_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& it) const {
      return data_ != it.data_ || index_ != it.index_;
    }

    Iterator& operator++() { ++index_; return *this; }
    Iterator& operator--() { --index_; return *this; }
    Iterator operator++(int) { return Iterator(*data_, index_++); }
    Iterator operator--(int) { return Iterator(*data_, index_--); }

    Iterator& operator+=(int offs) { index_ += offs; return *this; }
    Iterator& operator-=(int offs) { index_ -= offs; return *this; }
    Iterator operator+(int offs) { return Iterator(*data_, index_ + offs); }
    Iterator operator-(int offs) { return Iterator(*data_, index_ - offs); }
    int operator-(const Iterator& it) { return index_ - it.index_; }

    std::string& operator*() {
      return (*data_)[index_ / data_->size()][index_ % (*data_)[0].size()];
    }
    const std::string& operator*() const { return operator*(); }

   private:
    DataStore* data_;
    int index_;
  }; // class Iterator

  Iterator iterator() { return Iterator(data_); }
  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(data_, 0); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(data_, data_.size() * data_[0].size()); }

 private:
  DataStore& data_;
};  // class MyMatrix
```

Then `sort` could be applied to `MyMatrix` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > store = {
    { "5", "2", "1" },
    { "0", "0", "2" },
    { "1", "4", "3" }
  };

  MyMatrix matrix(store);

  for (const auto& row : store) {
    for (const auto& item : row) { std::cout << item <<' '; }
    std::cout <<'\n';
  }
  std::cout <<'\n';

  std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end());

  for (const auto& row : store) {
    for (const auto& item : row) { std::cout << item <<' '; }
    std::cout <<'\n';
  }
  std::cout <<'\n';
}
```

Running the above code will result in the following output:

```
5 2 1 
0 0 2 
1 4 3 

0 0 1 
1 2 2 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

To store a matrix, the nesting of `std::vector` is not the best solution. As any row manages its own size, there is no unique column size intrinsically granted by the matrix class.

Assuming that OP is damned to use an existing type (which may not be changed), I wrote my sample based on this.

One solution (with least implementation effort) would be

1. to copy the matrix (`std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >`) into a temporary of type `std::vector<std::string>`
2. apply `std::sort()` to this temporary
3. assign the sorted vector to matrix again.

Considering that moving of elements may be expensive, an alternative could be

1. to build up an index-pair vector
2. `std::sort()` it with a custom less functor (which considers matrix elements).

Afterwards, the index-pair vector may be used to access the original matrix elements in sorted order.

The latter is shown in my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Row;
typedef std::vector<Row> Matrix;
typedef std::pair<size_t, size_t> IndexPair;

struct LessMatrix {
  const Matrix &mat;
  LessMatrix(const Matrix &mat): mat(mat) { }
  bool operator()(const IndexPair &i1, const IndexPair &i2)
  {
    return mat[i1.first][i1.second] < mat[i2.first][i2.second];
  }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Matrix &mat)
{
  for (const Row row : mat) {
    for (const std::string elem : row) out << ' ' << elem;
    out << '\n';
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  Matrix mat = {
    { "5", "2", "1" },
    { "0", "0", "2" },
    { "1", "4", "3" }
  };
  // print input
  std::cout << "Input:\n" << mat << '\n';
  // indexify matrix
  std::vector<IndexPair> indices;
  for (size_t i = 0, n = mat.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    const std::vector<std::string> &row = mat[i];
    for (size_t j = 0, m = row.size(); j < m; ++j) {
      indices.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
    }
  }
  // sort matrix
  LessMatrix less(mat);
  std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), less);
  // print output
  Matrix matOut;
  { size_t i = 0; const size_t nCols = 3;
    for (const IndexPair &index : indices) {
      if (i % nCols == 0) matOut.push_back(Row());
      matOut.back().push_back(mat[index.first][index.second]);
      ++i;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Output:\n" << matOut << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input:
 5 2 1
 0 0 2
 1 4 3

Output:
 0 0 1
 1 2 2
 3 4 5
```

[<kbd>**Life demo on coliru**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f8a29b8b933d757)

---

The OP complained about creating a separate index vector. I suspected that a custom random access iterator might be a replacement (to sort the matrix directly). I must admit that I didn't do this before but, out of curiosity, I tried to puzzle this out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Row;
typedef std::vector<Row> Matrix;

struct MatrixIterator {
  typedef size_t difference_type;
  typedef std::string value_type;
  typedef std::string* pointer;
  typedef std::string& reference;
  typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;

  // accessed matrix
  Matrix &mat;
  // index of row, index of column
  size_t i, j;

  MatrixIterator(Matrix &mat, size_t i = 0, size_t j = 0): mat(mat), i(i), j(j) { }

  MatrixIterator& operator =(const MatrixIterator &iter)
  {
    assert(&mat == &iter.mat);
    i = iter.i; j = iter.j;
    return *this;
  }

  size_t nCols() const { return mat.front().size(); }

  std::string& operator *() { return mat[i][j]; }
  const std::string& operator *() const { return mat[i][j]; }

  MatrixIterator& operator ++() { return *this += 1; }
  MatrixIterator operator ++(int) { MatrixIterator iter(*this); ++*this; return iter; }

  MatrixIterator& operator --() { return *this -= 1; }
  MatrixIterator operator --(int) { MatrixIterator iter(*this); --*this; return iter; }

  MatrixIterator& operator += (size_t n)
  {
    j += i * nCols() + n; i = j / nCols(); j %= nCols(); return *this;
  }

  MatrixIterator operator + (size_t n) const
  {
    MatrixIterator iter(*this); iter += n; return iter;
  }
  friend MatrixIterator operator + (size_t n, const MatrixIterator &iter)
  {
    MatrixIterator iter2(iter); iter2 += n; return iter2;
  }

  MatrixIterator& operator -= (size_t n)
  {
    j += i * nCols() - n; i = j / nCols(); j %= nCols();
    return *this;
  }

  MatrixIterator operator - (size_t n) const
  {
    MatrixIterator iter(*this); iter -= n; return iter;
  }
  size_t operator - (const MatrixIterator &iter) const
  {
    return (i * nCols() + j) - (iter.i * iter.nCols() + iter.j);
  }

  std::string& operator[](size_t i) { return mat[i / nCols()][i % nCols()]; }
  const std::string& operator[](size_t i) const { return mat[i / nCols()][i % nCols()]; }

  bool operator == (const MatrixIterator &iter) const
  {
    return i == iter.i && j == iter.j;
  }
  bool operator != (const MatrixIterator &iter) const { return !(*this == iter); }

  bool operator < (const MatrixIterator &iter) const
  {
    return i * nCols() + j < iter.i * iter.nCols() + iter.j;
  }
  bool operator > (const MatrixIterator &iter) const { return iter < *this; }
  bool operator <= (const MatrixIterator &iter) const { return !(iter > *this); }
  bool operator >= (const MatrixIterator &iter) const { return !(*this < iter); }
};

MatrixIterator begin(Matrix &mat) { return MatrixIterator(mat, 0, 0); }
MatrixIterator end(Matrix &mat) { return MatrixIterator(mat, mat.size(), 0); }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Matrix &mat)
{
  for (const Row row : mat) {
    for (const std::string elem : row) out << ' ' << elem;
    out << '\n';
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  Matrix mat = {
    { "5", "2", "1" },
    { "0", "0", "2" },
    { "1", "4", "3" }
  };
  // print input
  std::cout << "Input:\n" << mat << '\n';
  // sort matrix
  std::sort(begin(mat), end(mat));
  // print output
  std::cout << "Output:\n" << mat << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input:
 5 2 1
 0 0 2
 1 4 3

Output:
 0 0 1
 1 2 2
 3 4 5
```

[<kbd>**Life demo on coliru**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dafdc90540cf082f)

Notes:

I used the descriptions on cppreference.com

- [C++ concepts: RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)
- [C++ concepts: BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)
- [C++ concepts: ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator)
- [C++ concepts: Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator)
- [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)

as a "requirement-cheat-sheet" and implemented everything described there. Some of the details, I decided by guess. (Especially, concerning the `typedef`s I'm not quite sure how to do them correct.)

Comment: It is a good solution but I don't want to go through all the elements twice

Comment: @polmonroig `std::sort()` requires two [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) to describe begin and end of range to sort. If you create your own random access iterator (which provides access to element in nested vector) then you can `std::sort()` the matrix directly, and the index array becomes obsolete. I must admit I never did this before - so it's rather an academical statement...

Comment: @polmonroig Here we go: an update with random access iterator. This looks somehow creepy to me. In real world projects, I would stick to a `class Matrix` with a single `vector` inside where row/column indexing is done in dedicated get()/set() methods.

Comment: @polmonroig I just saw that somebody else provided an answer with a similar idea meanwhile - my bad...